# How to provide upload function for users

Tags: files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to allow users upload images to existing nodes?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5476/how-to-allow-users-upload-images-to-existing-nodes)

How might I go about providing a page for authenticated users to upload image files to the server?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

- Use a contributed module.  Take a look at this link for a list of modules: [File Uploading and Managing](http://groups.drupal.org/node/20291). A few that are definitely worth taking a look at are: [FileDepot](http://drupal.org/project/filedepot), [WebFM](http://drupal.org/project/webfm), and [ELfinder](http://drupal.org/project/elfinder)
- Create a content type where you can upload files (using the core image module if D7 or if D6, the [Image](http://drupal.org/project/image) or [ImageField](http://drupal.org/project/imagefield) modules)
- Create a custom module to your exact specifications.  This is definitely the most customizable option, but involves more work and a familiarity with the API. To get started creating a custom module, take a look at the [Module developer's guide](http://drupal.org/developing/modules), the [Forms API Reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6), and the [Form API Quickstart Guide](http://drupal.org/node/751826)

Comment: The function isn't for a content admin. I want to provide the user an html form with the file tag, so the browser produces a browse element for them to select their file and click upload. I thought I'd just stuff the html form into a page that sends it to a page for processing, but it just seems like there must be a Drupal way. It's not clear than any of the modules  you suggested will do that. Or will I definitely have to create my own module for this?

Comment: The few contributed modules I listed will allow you to set permissions on who can upload and to where, but if you are looking to add a file upload function to a custom form, you will probably have to write a custom module (or possibly use the Webform module).  If you choose to write your own module, take a look at that option in my answer again, I have updated my answer

Comment: Ok, so I think you've answered my question. There's no easy way to do this without writing a custom module. Thanks for linking to the docs!

Answer (score 0):

use the image module, it will let you attach images to nodes as well as to create image content, you can go to user permissions to assign the image create and image attach privilege to authenticated user role.